# fails, but no error object is returned. Why?

Tags: objective-c, error-handling, nsdata

I'm trying to understand the meaning of the value returned by [[NSData writeToFile:options:error:]](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSData/writeToFile:options:error:). The method returns a BOOL, which according to Apple's documentation is "YES if the operation succeeds, otherwise NO."

Fair enough, but if it's NO, I would have assumed that the error parameter would then be set to some retrievable NSError* value. However in results I'm coming across, that's not the case. Accordingly I'm somewhat confused, and don't know how to determine what caused the failure.

To wit, I've got this code (more or less):

```
NSError* error = nil;
BOOL success = [data writeToFile: filePath error: &error];
if ( error )
    NSLog( @"error = %@", [error description] );
```

`success` turns out to be `NO` in the code I'm running, but the `NSLog` statement is never executed. How come?

Howard

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's possible that `data` is `nil`, in which case `[data writeToFile:error:]` returns `nil`, but `*error` is not set.

Comment: That's exactly what it is. Thank you. I've never been bitten before by the fact you can send a message to the nil object; At last: I now consider myself a true Objective-C programmer! :-)

Comment: That messages to nil object almost always makes me kill couple of hours :)

Answer (score 0):

The writeToFile method returns TRUE on success and FALSE on failure -that's what you want to actually check for.

So, Try:

```
if(!success)
```

As your conditional instead of if( error ).

Comment: I've tried success == NO, but in that case (and I presume in the case of trying your shorter form as well), the emitted log statement is 'error = (null)'. That's what I'm not understanding.

Comment: IMO for a decent error handling you should check both success and error,
if data is nil, you will not succeed but will have no error, in this case you should tell something to user